# How to use regular expression to match case insensitive unicode character?

Tags: php, regex, case-insensitive

I'm trying to use regular expression with php to match both upper case and lower case unicode character.

Here is my example code:

```
$s = "a à À";
$s = preg_replace("/à/iU", "a", $s);
echo $s;
```

But didn't success, anyone can help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works:

```
$s = "a à À";
echo preg_replace('/à/iu', "a", $s);
```

**Output:**

```
a a a
```

Use `/u` not `/U` flag for unicode characters in your regex. `U` is for un-greedy (lazy) matching.